# What can cause keys added to a Hashtable to be null?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

Using the .NET Micro Framework 4.1

I'm adding the following string keys (and string values, not relevant here) to a hashtable:

```
"eth::address"
"eth::netmask"
"eth::gateway"
"eth::dns"
"eth::port"
"com::baudrate"
"com::parity"
"com::databits"
"com::stopbits"
"com::handshake"
"com::read-timeout"
"com::write-timeout"
"drv::led-firmware-file"
"scr::width"
"scr::height"
"scr::colors"
```

When adding these to the HashTable no errors are thrown.

However, when looking at the properties & content of the hashtable
I can see the following:

16 buckets, but 6 of them have a null key and null value.
It's always the same ones.

What could be causing this?

Update:

There's not much code to post:

```
var settings = new HashTable(16);
settings.Add("eth::address", "192.168.1.1");
//Keep adding the settings mentioned above
```

No exceptions are thrown, in the end there are 16
items in the hashtable, starting with 3 valid ones, then a few null ones, then a few valid ones, etc....

There's nothing else involved as this is a simply a test case

[image: The tool to inspect is #vs2010]

If I try to get one of the values that "got lost",
an exception is thrown:

```
var x = settings["eth::port"];
```

Will result in:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll


enter code here
```

Comment: You might need to post some more code.

Comment: There's not much more to post I'm afraid

Comment: How are you looking at the properties of the hashtable?  Can you reproduce the problem in code, or is it only visible in the debugger?

Comment: So what you're saying is that a `HashTable` is losing entries?

Comment: Try define your hashtable without a capacity just for the test

Comment: The code that you use to inspect this table would be relivant. We have all dealt with situations in the past where the data was fine, but the means of inspecting the data was flawed.

Comment: In the debugger, scroll down past entry 16 to find the missing entries.

Comment: @Jeffrey :p that would have been nice :p But nope... I think this might be something specified to the MF, ran into oddities like this before.

Comment: You should consider whether the HashTable is doing reference equality on your strings, in which case the lookup might fail even though the string values are equal. To fix that, specify the equality comparison to use when you create the HashTable. It is also possible that the implementation of the HashTable is buggy, since it shows 16 buckets in the debugger, and HashTables normally don't use non-prime sizes. Non-standard uses of non-generic collections on unusual platforms might sometimes be buggy.

Comment: @TimothyP What happens if you just add 16 random strings to the hashtable..? Generated by a for loop or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend Volkan's answer - checking the internal implementation of `Hashtable` one might find the following:

```
public Hashtable(int capacity) : this(capacity, (float) 1f)
{
}

public Hashtable(int capacity, float loadFactor)
{
    // arguments checking - elided

    this.loadFactor = 0.72f * loadFactor;
    double num = ((float) capacity) / this.loadFactor;
    if (num > 2147483647.0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_HTCapacityOverflow"));
    }
    int num2 = (num > 3.0) ? HashHelpers.GetPrime((int) num) : 3;
    this.buckets = new bucket[num2];
    this.loadsize = (int) (this.loadFactor * num2);
    this.isWriterInProgress = false;
}
```

So what happens when you initialize it with `new Hashtable(16)`...? First, `num`'s value is computed to `16/0.72 = 22.(2)`. Then, `HashHelpers.GetPrime(22)` kicks in, which looks like this:

```
internal static int GetPrime(int min)
{
    // arguments checking - elided

    for (int i = 0; i < primes.Length; i++)
    {
        int num2 = primes[i];
        if (num2 >= min)
        {
            return num2;
        }
    }

    // more code; irrelevant in this case - elided
}
```

Almost there. We only need to look up what `primes` is.

```
static HashHelpers()
{
    primes = new int[] { 3, 7, 11, 17, 23 /* more values */ };
}
```

With `22` as `min` argument, we can easily see `GetPrime` returns `23`. And this is the value used in `Hashtable` constructor to create buckets array. You can perform same analysis for micro framework to see why it creates 16 buckets (which is weird TBH, considering it's good practice for buckets number to be prime value).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to micro framework, but for .NET 4.0, i tested with sample you gave and it allocates 23 buckets, 7 of them has null values. Each value is placed in the bucket with its hash code % 23. For example, eth::gateway has hash code of 1866092901 and its modulus 23 is 22 so its placed in 22th bucket. Why do you worry about hash tables internal bucket allocation strategy? Try code below in Linqpad and you can be sure:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] vals = {"eth::address", "eth::netmask", .. all other strings... };
    var ht = new Hashtable(16);
    foreach (var v in vals) 
          ht[v] = v;
    var m = typeof(Hashtable).GetField("buckets", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    m.GetValue(ht).Dump();
    ht.Dump();
}
```